# Trying to run a set of calculations but faced with a Overflow Error

Tags: python, error-handling

I am trying to get the equation `(2^g - p) / x` to run with my code but I am encountering Overflow errors. I was wondering if there is a way to go around this issue.

```
import math as m
import decimal as d

d.getcontext().prec = 100000000000000

variable = int(input("Enter Number: "))

def Namespace(x): # the point of this function is to put input shift variables to find a whole number result
    g = 1
    p = 1
    D = []
    while len(D) == 0:
            if x < (2**g-p):
                count = 0
            while count != 3:
                f = ((2**g)-p)/x # Here is where the Error Happens
                a = m.log(f,3)
                if a.is_integer == True:
                    c = [d.Decimal(a), d.Decimal(g)] # adds Decimal to List
                    D.append(c)
                    count = 3
                else:
                    g += 1
                    count += 1
        else:
            g +=1
        p = find_next_prime(p+1)

    print(D)

def find_next_prime(n):
    return find_prime_in_range(n, 2*n)

def find_prime_in_range(a, b):
    for p in range(a, b):
        for i in range(2, p):
            if p % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            return p
    return None

Namespace(variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hardly a surprise that it has an overflow problem when you ask for one hundred trillion places after the decimal point. Did you mean to specify that it should be capable of handling numbers up to 15 places? For which you should specify,

```
d.getcontext().prec = 15
```

That many decimal places would exceed the mass storage capacity of almost any computer in the world, never mind the RAM.